# BitmapFactory getWidth() getHeight() and pixels from actual picture size differ

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I am a novice in Android Studio, and out of everything I am especially confused in tasks relating to BitmapFactory.

The problem I have is as followed. When I insert a jpg file with dimension(578x496) under drawable folder, and I do this

```
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.background1));
Log.e("WIDTH", String.valueOf(mBitmap.getWidth());
Log.e("HEIGHT", String.valueOf(mBitmap.getHeight());
```

What I get is a dimension of (2312x1984), which exactly x4 bigger than the actual dimension. Is it because I have the file format as jpg and not png?

So what I decided to do was

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4;
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.background1,options));
```

and then set it as a background of my SurfaceView by,

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
   public static final int WIDTH=578;
   public static final int HEIGHT=496;
   ....
   @Override
   public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    final int scaleXFactor = getWidth()/WIDTH;
    final int scaleYFactor = getHeight()/HEIGHT;

    if(canvas!=null){
        final int savedState = canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(scaleXFactor,scaleYFactor);
        bg.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restoreToCount(savedState);
    }

}
```

but this canvas.scale(scaleXFactor,scaleYFactor) only allow the background to fit horizontally but not vertically. So it is like

```
--------------------------------------    
|                IMG                  |
|                                     |
|-------------------------------------|   <-Viewed as "Landscape"
|         Black Empty Screen          |
|                                     |
|-------------------------------------|
```

My understanding so far is that Bitmap is really important concept in any kinds of applications made from Android Studio, and when not implemented correctly, it causes application to crash through OOM error or simple slow down the application. Please shed me some light on this poor man, experts out there.

Comment: It is because you use decodeResource() from drawable folder. An image is adapted for the device then. What is the resolution of the screen? Although i find it strange that it becomes that big. Put your picture in assets folder and use decode from stream or so.

Comment: @greenapps you were right on that it automatically resizes the Bitmap and scales with the resolution of the screen. I put resources in assets folder and it works, although I am not looking for doing it that way

Comment: Do you have another suggestion in doing this so that the image does not get resized automatically? I really appreciate your input man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have an image in `/res/drawable` or `/res/drawable-mdpi` folder, and you call `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` on a device with `xxxhdpi` density, `BitmapFactory` will scale up the bitmap for you, so that when you display it on the `xxxhdpi` screen, it will look proportionately the same as on a lower density screen.

If you've decided that you *really* don't want this to happen, place the image in the `/res/drawable-nodpi` folder.  Then it will decode at the same size on every platform.  The image will look very different across different density devices when you display it, however.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did put that under -nodpi folder and that different in size problem is done. (I know it is only  temporary solution this way). So when I want other densities such as "xxxdpi" , I need to increase the resolution of the image higher or else it will resize it for me in an unwanted way?

Comment: I should have looked at your code more closely.  When you run `scaleXFactor = getWidth()/WIDTH`, and I'm assuming that the width of your `SurfaceView` is 578dp, you are handling density yourself.  I'll bet the width of your view is 2312, or 4 * 578. So you scale the canvas then draw the image with density-**in**dependent nodpi decode, but that's no different that if you *didn't* call `canvas.scale()` then drew the image with the density-dependent decode you started with.  In the first case you scale on drawing, in the second case you scale on decoding.  The end result is the same regardless.

Answer (score 0):

[`BitmapFactory.decodeResource`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory#decodeResource(android.content.res.Resources,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)) can take a third argument `opts` of type [`BitmapFactory.Options`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options).

you can set the options to explicitly prevent any scaling:

```kotlin
val options = BitmapFactory.Options().apply {
                    inScaled = false
                }
```

and update your call with this additional parameter like so:

```kotlin
val bitmap: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        getResources(),
                        R.drawable.background1, 
                        options)
```

When you request `width` and `height` from your `bitmap`, it will return the true-to-file values, without any scaling.